# Django : return two string for self - Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a Python model and I would like to return a combination of two fields : `category` + `name`.

The only thing is that the category field is a relationship, and within the category table, it is a "name" field. Note that the `__str__` is the name.

---

Example :

**Category table**:
*id 1* "hot"

**Product table**: *id 1* "chocolate"

**In Django-Admin** (what I except): "hot chocolate"

---

Here is the code :

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('product_name'), max_length=55)
    image = models.CharField(_('product_image'),max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(_('product_description'), max_length=500)
    price = models.DecimalField(_('product_price'), max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categorie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(selfProduct):
        return self.category + self.name
```

---

The error is the following : **unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Categorie' and 'str'**

Thanks!

Comment: what is the question here? at a guess you need `self.category.name + self.name`

Comment: @JoranBeasley this return a non-string

Comment: are you getting an error? please show us not only what you expect (ie "Hot Chocolate"), but also what your actual output that you are not expecting is.

Comment: ok now we are getting close ... `self.category.name + self.name` at a guess ... or maybe `str(self.category) + self.name` if you have overloaded the str function on your `Category` class

Answer (score 1):

*It is clear that we are discussing dajngo admin issue*

Change method to:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s, %s' ( self.category.whatever-field-in-the-category-model, self.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the + operand 2 strings. So `str(self.category) + self.name` would work. Or perhaps `self.category.name + self.name` if the category has a `name` attribute.

Be aware, that accessing the Category object might cause a lot of queries making your admin slow.

Answer (score 0):

This format works use +

```
return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

To include fields from other tables use self.tablename.fieldname

```
return self.category.name + " " + self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the python string format method.

```
return "{} {}".format(self.category, self.name)
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `return self.category + self.name`

To `return str('%s %s' % (self.category, self.name))`